# Override parent styling to have divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I know that there are similar questions, but those solutions are not working for me. I am wondering how to OVERRIDE PARENT STYLES. My page is contained in a master page, which has many styles and classes.

For some reason I applied the following CSS but it's not working at all because both `<div>`s are not side by side. Both are taking the full width of the screen. So the second is below the first `<div>`.

So I wanna forget all style in the page and make this work.

Here is my code:

```css
.mysection {
  margin: 0px;
}

.mysection > div#first {
  margin: 0px;
  float: left !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 350px !important;
}

.mysection > div#second {
  margin-left: 15%;
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 350px !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="mysection">
  <div class="first">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
    <asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server">
      <div>Test1</div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <h1>My Title 2</h2>
    <div>Test2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this: `.mysection > div#first` to `.mysection > .first`. Same for `.second`.

`#first` refers to an element with the `id="first"` whereas `.first` refers to an element the with `class="first"`. The prepended `div` after the child selector is also unnecessary.

You also closed one of your `<h1>` tags with `</h2>` on accident. It's fixed below:

```css
.mysection {
  margin: 0px;
}

.mysection > .first {
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
}

.mysection > .second {
  margin-left: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<section class="mysection">
  <div class="first">
  <h1>My Title</h1>
    <asp:Panel ID="myPanel" runat="server">
      <div>Test1</div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <h1>My Title 2</h1>
    <div>Test2</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood. NOW both DIVs are side by side(EXCELLENT), but all the content that is now below the section it's like mounted on the section. It's like "mysection" had a short height. How can I do to make it block and avoid the mount. I added to "mysection" the style "display: block;" but I got nothing

Comment: @MaximusDecimus, add blank div with style clear after second div like `<div style="clear:both"></div>` and your problem will solve.

Comment: OH. That's what you meant. Yes, the float has to be cleared, or I believe `overflow: hidden;` would also work. It's because the `float` is causing the height to be `0` IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

you use to css `ID` & HTML use to `class` Change to `id` to `class`

```
.mysection div.first{
        margin: 0px;
        float: left !important;
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 350px !important;
    }

    .mysection div.second{
        margin-left: 15%;
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 350px !important;
    }
```